Prove that $2^ + 3$ is divisible by $2^{ + } − 9$ only if $ =  = 2$
For $a$ and $b$ positive integers, I want to show that $2^ + 3$ is divisible by  $2^{ + } − 9$  only if  $ =  = 2$ and no other solutions exist. Note that I am only interested in the case  of $2^{ + } − 9 > 0$
If $2^ + 3$ is divisible by  $2^{ + } − 9$  then it exist a positive odd integer $k$ such that:
$2^ + 3 = k\cdot(2^{ + } − 9)$

$k$ is odd as both $2^ + 3$ and $2^{ + } − 9$ are odd as I am adding/subtracting an odd number (3 and 9) to an even one.
 I can then rearrange the above equation as:
$2^a(k\cdot2^b-1) = 3\cdot(1+3k) $
Clearly, $(k\cdot2^b-1)$ is odd while $(1+3k) $ is even. I can therefore say that there must be a positive odd $m$ such as:
 $k\cdot2^b-1 =3\cdot m$ and  $1+3k =2^a\cdot m$
The above conditions indicate that $k\cdot2^b-1$ must be a multiple of 3 therefore excluding any $k$ values that are multiples of 3. This is as far as I went. Could someone help figuring out a complete mathematical demonstration?

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Did you mean to specify $2^{a+b}-9>0$? If not, we could also take $a=b=1$ so $2^a+3=5,,2^{a+b}-9=-5$.

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I'm curious where this question came from

Since $2^{a+b}-9|2^a+3,$ we know that $2^{a+b}-9≤2^a+3$ and hence $2^{a+b}≤2^a+12.$ Divide this inequality out by $2^a$ to get $2^b≤1+\frac{12}{2^a}.$
If $a=1,$ we get $2^b≤7.$ This means $b$ is either $1$ or $2.$ Check that neither works.
If $a=2,$ we get $2^b≤4.$ Again, $b$ is either $1$ or $2.$ Check that $b=2$ works but $b=1$ doesn't.
If $a=3,$ we get that $2^b≤\frac{5}{2}.$ This gives $b=1.$ Check that it doesn't work.
If $a≥4,$ we have that $1+\frac{12}{2^a}<2,$ and hence $2^b<2,$ which is not possible for $b\in\mathbb{N}.$
Conclude that if $2^{a+b}-9|2^a+3,$ then, $a=b=2.$

Nice approach. I am wondering if there are alternative proofs that are not based on the condition that the numerator is greater than the denominator.
